# OpenGL window sizing rendering issue

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When I create a new GLUT/openGL program the window sizing makes the top of the screen +1 and the bottom -1 in the x direction, I would like the coordinates to match the pixel size of the window.  I want to do this because when I reshape my window the project is distorted.  All I'm looking for is the name of the function I should read into.

Comment: on resize you need to adjust the aspect ratio by getting the new window size and hight, here a good example from another post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267243/in-opengl-how-can-i-adjust-for-the-window-being-resized

Answer (score 0):

This function is part of my project and it prevent distortion.

```
GLvoid myWidget::resizeGL(GLint width, GLint height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0,                  //The camera angle
                   (double)width / height,//The width-to-height ratio
                   1.0,                   //The near z clipping coordinate
                   100.0);                //The far z clipping coordinate
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my project

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
if (height==0)  // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
{
    height=1;   // Making Height Equal One
}

w_screen=width;                     // GLWidget members (u don't need these)
h_screen=height;                    //
float ratio=width/height; 

glViewport(0,0,width,height);   // Reset The Current Viewport

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(fov,ratio,0.1f,200.0f); 

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}
```

fov in my case is a public member (initialized to 45)

Hope it helps