# C# OpenTk scale object with on screen resize and camera size

Tags: c#, 2d, textures, viewport, opentk

Look at the those images [minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhcmt.png) [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBz0A.png)
The minimized window created with 2 texture is right, but in the fullscreen window i dont know how to fix, i dont know if i should scale the texture or zoom the camera but im noob with opentk, if someone can help me with some code. I dont post any code becouse i dont really know how to fix it..
Thanks and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the OnResize method and change the projection matrix

[In OpenGL, how can I adjust for the window being resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267243/in-opengl-how-can-i-adjust-for-the-window-being-resized)

If you are using immediate mode then this will help, other wise you will need to change the projection matrix in the shaders you are using.